# Two separated buttons for kostysh upload function in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: button, file-upload, sencha-touch-2

I use in one Sencha Touch 2 project the Kostysh Upload Function with Fileup.js and getfile.php:
https://github.com/kostysh/File-uploading-component-for-Sencha-Touch

My question is how I can make in that view, for the Upload Function, two separated buttons:
one for Browse and One for Submit (Upload)? I tryed to create an other button named 'upload' with handler event to auto-tap the default button. (I was thinking that if I try to auto-click the button after that is already in "ready" stats, will upload automatically).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution. You can make one additional button that can trigger the upload function from fileup.js with:

```
Ext.getCmp('newbtnId').onButtonTap();
```

- "onButtonTap()" function is defined in fileup.js

And will upload your browsed image. A little tricky if you tried like me with autoclick ideas from outside...